# How many minority-majority districts are there?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, statistics, demographics

I want to know more about minority-majority districts. How many of them are there, and what percentage of minority-majority districts are represented by Democrats in the House of Representatives?

It is important to note that white alone is not same as white alone not hispanic or latino.

Comment: That  sounds like an oxymoron?

Comment: @user253751: In this context, “minority” refers to racial minorities (i.e., non-White people), who are a majority within the individual Congressional district.

Comment: @dan04 Then they're obviously not a minority in that district...

Answer (score 5):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_majority-minority_United_States_congressional_districts):

There are 23 districts with a majority African American electorate, and 1 with a majority Asian American electorate.

All 24 are represented by members of the Democratic Party, and all except Rep Steve Cohen (TN-9) identify as Black or Asian.

There are also 20-odd districts with a majority Hispanic (any race).

(Note that the wikipedia list is somewhat out of date)

Answer (score 3):

Using the latest available (2018) data from the [American Community Survey](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs), we can obtain a list of congressional districts with a minority-majority population - that is to say, districts where the proportion of the population identifying as 'White Alone' is less than 50%.

Of the 435 congressional districts, as well as Puerto Rico & D.C.'s non-voting delegates, 58 have a minority-majority population. All 58 are represented in the 116th Congress by Democratic representatives, except for Georgia's 5th Congressional District, which is currently vacant following Democratic Rep. John Lewis' death in July 2020.

Below is a map showing the location of these 58 districts, categorized by the largest racial demographic within the district.

[image]

Below is the full list of minority-majority districts for the 116th Congress:

```
Congressional District,Pop.,White Alone Pop.,Percent White Alone
NY-15,743959,128998,17.34
HI-1,709286,122457,17.26
NY-5,757972,132518,17.48
NY-13,795633,203890,25.63
TN-9,712723,188242,26.41
GA-4,785104,210961,26.87
MD-4,760398,211823,27.86
CA-17,777468,222919,28.67
NJ-10,759704,218853,28.81
GA-13,757521,220074,29.05
NY-8,791211,246189,31.12
LA-2,794121,247841,31.21
MS-2,695797,218531,31.41
HI-2,711205,223195,31.38
GA-5,793039,251276,31.69
PA-3,736340,242730,32.96
AL-7,660468,221541,33.54
TX-9,786925,265656,33.76
CA-34,748812,259995,34.72
MI-14,704494,244398,34.69
MD-7,716136,251762,35.16
NY-9,730957,262344,35.89
FL-20,809153,295544,36.53
IL-2,694459,253856,36.55
IL-7,707513,264669,37.41
CA-27,705509,266686,37.80
SC-6,659483,256307,38.86
MI-13,663867,260452,39.23
OH-11,678001,269493,39.75
CA-15,789174,314637,39.87
CA-38,716331,292100,40.78
CA-43,753696,307860,40.85
CA-13,764304,312333,40.87
DC-1,702455,296747,42.24
NY-14,706440,298774,42.29
GA-2,665539,281955,42.36
NY-6,734183,313127,42.65
FL-24,784469,337035,42.96
IL-1,706550,303613,42.97
CA-14,759415,328620,43.27
MO-1,728365,315884,43.37
CA-19,763028,334224,43.80
CA-44,725177,320876,44.25
VA-3,744804,330195,44.33
CA-35,769589,341427,44.36
FL-5,738862,331585,44.88
NY-16,732981,334077,45.58
PA-2,727380,333199,45.81
NC-12,880550,405087,46.00
MD-5,757621,358663,47.34
NC-1,761087,363018,47.70
CA-12,764043,365047,47.78
WA-9,765285,367222,47.98
CA-37,738174,355343,48.14
TX-18,801885,388019,48.39
WI-4,710573,351094,49.41
NV-1,685427,339750,49.57
CA-6,777985,386232,49.65
```

Comment: Which ACS table did you use? If you use the table B03003 "Hispanic or Latino Origin," you find that there is a district in Florida, a district in California, and five districts in Texas that are 75% or more Hispanic. CA-40, TX-34, TX-15, TX-16, TX-29, TX-28, FL-25.

Comment: Maybe B03002 "HISPANIC OR LATINO ORIGIN BY RACE" would be an even better choice, since it breaks out "Not Hispanic or Latino: White Alone" from "Hispanic or Latino: White Alone."